# DART pubspec.yml error with html and bootstrap package

Tags: dart, bootstrap-4, angular-dart, dart-html, dart-analyzer

I get error with the bootstrap version 3.3.7. When I update bootstrap to 4.0.0, error goes away but I do not want to update as there are lot of breaking changes.

Resolving dependencies...
Package html has no versions that match >=0.12.2+1 <0.13.0 derived from:
- analyzer 0.29.11 depends on version >=0.12.0 <1.14.0
- angular 4.0.0+2 depends on version >=0.12.0 <0.14.0
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter 1.0.1 depends on version ^0.12.2+1

This is my pubspec.yml 
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.24.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
  angular: ^4.0.0+2
  angular_forms: ^1.0.0
  angular_router: ^1.0.2
  angular_components: ^0.6.0
  json_object: any
  http: any
  html: any
  angular_dart_ui_bootstrap: '>=0.0.1'
  ng_bootstrap: ^0.8.5
  bootstrap: "^3.3.7"
  dartson: "^0.2.7"
  browser_detect: "^1.0.4"
  archive: "^1.0.33"
  build: "^0.11.0"
  intl: "^0.15.6"
  stream_transformers: "^0.3.0"
  rxdart: "^0.10.2"

dev_dependencies:
  browser: ^0.10.0
  dart_to_js_script_rewriter: ^1.0.1
  test: ^0.12.0
  angular_test: ^1.0.0

transformers:
- dartson
- angular:
    entry_points:
      - web/main.dart
      - test/**_test.dart

- test/pub_serve:
  $include: test/**_test.dart
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter

Comment: Which Dart SDK version are you using?

Comment: Dart VM version: 1.24.3

Comment: It'll be REALLY hard to debug this with Dart 1.x. Dart 2 has a much better version solver for pub that can help with errors.

Comment: I upgraded to Dart 2 . Looks like Dart 2 is  not compatible with bootstrap 3 . ERROR:  The current Dart SDK version is 2.0.0. 
Because WebUI depends on bootstrap >=3.3.0+3 which requires SDK version <2.0.0, version solving failed.

Comment: See this trick, but in reverse: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/announce/dX6BJgYYmBE/ycPh1TTYAAAJ

Try running `_PUB_TEST_SDK_VERSION=2.0.0-dev pub upgrade`

Comment: _PUB_TEST_SDK_VERSION=2.0.0 pub upgrade
Resolving dependencies... (6.4s)
The current Dart SDK version is 2.0.0.

Because WebUI depends on bootstrap >=3.3.0+3 which requires SDK version <2.0.0, version solving failed.

Comment: _PUB_TEST_SDK_VERSION=2.0.0-dev pub upgrade
Resolving dependencies...
The current Dart SDK version is 2.0.0-dev.

Because WebUI requires SDK version >=2.0.0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.

Comment: .Tried with bootstrap: ^4.0.0 . with Dart 2 .                                               Because bootstrap 4.0.0 requires SDK version <2.0.0 and no versions of bootstrap match >4.0.0 <5.0.0, bootstrap ^4.0.0 is forbidden.
So, because WebUI depends on bootstrap ^4.0.0, version solving failed

Comment: Is this a issue or am i missing something . Any suggestion would help us to upgrade/change supported libs .